# How to make different menu options in different Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, menu

I want to have completely different `menu options` in different `fragment`.I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23338937/how-can-i-change-option-menu-in-different-fragments) post.But my fragment menu is adding with the activity menu.But i don't want to have activity menus in some of my fragments.
In `SlidingDrawerActivity`:

```
  @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

In my fragment:

```
public Friends_Status_Comment_Fragment(){
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }
  @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_add_comment,menu);
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);

    }
```

The Activities items are adding with the menu of fragment.How to stop it???

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'm not sure if I underestand your problem - in your fragment you should clear menu and create new one - and don't call super :) something like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater){
    menu.clear();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_add_comment,menu);
}
```

Comment: will these previous menu will be back when i go back??

Comment: yes - if in your activity you will have onCreateOptionsMenu() menu will be recreated