# Menu toolbar showing in wrong fragment

Tags: java, android, toolbar

I have a main activity and two fragments, I need the buttons change when I swipe the fragments but in the first fragment de not show buttons in the toolbar and in the second fragment shows the button of the first fragment, if the second fragmento do not have buttons in toolbar the first works fine.`

this is the first fragment

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }


}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    View vista =inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_clientes, container, false);

    Toolbar barra_principal = vista.findViewById(R.id.barra);
    ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(barra_principal);


@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(@NonNull Menu menu, @NonNull MenuInflater inflater) {

    inflater.inflate(R.menu.busqueda_menu,menu);
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.busqueda);
    searchView = (SearchView) item.getActionView();
    searchView.setQueryHint("Busqueda Id, Nombre, Dirección");


    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String textoBusqueda) {

            adaptador.getFilter().filter(textoBusqueda);

            return false;
        }
    });

    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id==R.id.busqueda){
        //Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Busqueda",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }else if (id==R.id.busquedadia){

        if(lydias.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
            lydias.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }else{
            lydias.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

this is the second fragment.

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    AdaptadorProductos adaptador;
    manager = new dbManager(getContext());




    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View vista =inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_productos_, container, false);
    Toolbar barra_principal = vista.findViewById(R.id.barra);
    ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(barra_principal);

    listaProductos = new ArrayList<>();

    rcvProductos = vista.findViewById(R.id.rcvProductos);
    rcvProductos.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

    llenaLista();



    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return vista;
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(@NonNull Menu menu, @NonNull MenuInflater inflater) {

    inflater.inflate(R.menu.busqueda_menu,menu);
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.busqueda);
    searchView = (SearchView) item.getActionView();
    searchView.setQueryHint("Busqueda Id, Descripción,");


    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String textoBusqueda) {

            adaptador.getFilter().filter(textoBusqueda);

            return false;
        }
    });

    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id==R.id.busqueda){
        //Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Busqueda",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }else if (id==R.id.busquedadia){


    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: It looks like each Fragment has its own Toolbar, is that correct? Why are you using `setSupportActionBar()` and those APIs at all instead of just using the `Toolbar` APIs directly?

Comment: Yes a use one toolbar for each fragment, setSupporActionBar() is for custom action bar. I must use only one toolbar? how i manage te events for each fragment?

Comment: What do you mean 'for custom action bar'? Are you actually using any of the ActionBar APIs (i.e., calling `getSupportActionBar()` anywhere)? Or is it just for showing the menus for Fragments?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the similar issue: see [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28098972/3340706)

```java
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater){
    menu.clear();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_add_comment,menu);
}
```

Comment: I made the similar project but could not get any problem with menu buttons in different fragments. Maybe something is wrong in your MainActivity or layouts. Try to start a new project from built-in Bottom Navigation activity - disable Actionbar by using NoActionBar theme is styles.xml and put your custom toolbars in each fragment.