# Android: change menu depending on selected fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a diferent fragments but I want to change the options menu. I want that only the "Solicitudes" have it

[The fragment that I want to have this option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zFiJ1.jpg)

[This fragment shouldn't have it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4zwX.jpg)

I have a menu folder with the main.xml and actually I create another main2.xml that doesn't have this settings option but I don't know how to change this

Here's my code so far:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

    fragment = new History();
```

The oncreate:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

And the code for the History fragment:

```
public class History extends Fragment {
public static final String ARG_HISTORY = "arg_history";

public History() {
    // Empty constructor required for fragment subclasses
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.history, container, false);
    return rootView;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `Fragment` you need to say that this `Fragment` controls the menu.

In your `Fragment`'s `onCreate`.

```
setHasOptionsMenu(true);
```

Now you can implement the following in your `Fragment` to hide the `MenuItem` you don't want.

```
    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        menu.findItem(R.id.unwanted_item).setVisible(false);
    }
```

Make sure you do the reverse in the `Fragment` you do want the `MenuItem` in.

If you want to add a `MenuItem` that is not in the `Menu` loaded by your `Activity` do the following in the `onCreateOptionsMenu` in your `Fragment`.

```
    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_to_add_to_original, menu);
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }
```

Comment: I only have one onCreateOptionsMenu, now none layout has the action_settings but if I only have one onCreateOptionsMenu how do I change in the fragment where I want the MenuItem?

Comment: Have modified answer. Is this what you meant?

Comment: Not really because if I modify the onCreateOptionsMenu it will modify all the fragments, I don't have one onCreateOptionsMenu per fragment

Comment: Well I add the onCreateOptionsMenu on the fragment and it works :) thank you very much !